# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not foundが発生してしまう

Tags: android, opencv

失礼いたします。

現在、趣味でOpenCVのAndroid版を使ったアプリを作っております。
しかし、アプリを実行すると、LogCatに題目のエラーが発生した後、強制終了してしまいます。

ソースは以下の通りです。
以下の通り、画像処理の部分についてはAndroidNDKの機能を使用しております。

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.foo;

import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String    TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Mat                    mMatCamera;
    private Mat                    mMatView;

    private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        } else {
            System.loadLibrary("foo");
        }
    }

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.foo);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.foo_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mMatView = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        if (mMatCamera != null)
            mMatCamera.release();
        if (mMatView != null)
            mMatView.release();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mMatCamera = inputFrame.rgba();

        foo(mMatCamera.getNativeObjAddr(), mMatView.getNativeObjAddr());

        return mMatView;
    }

    private native void foo(long matCameraAddr, long matViewAddr);
}
```

jni_part.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_foo_MainActivity_foo(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong matCameraAddr, jlong matViewAddr)
{
    // 何か処理
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

エラーの内容は以下の通りです。

```
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-157860
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065): Process: com.example.foo, PID: 26065
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.foo.MainActivity.foo:(JJ)V
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065):    at com.example.foo.MainActivity.foo(Native Method)
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065):    at com.example.foo.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:81)
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065):    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
03-08 10:58:42.984: E/AndroidRuntime(26065):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNIからネイティブメソッド実体を見つけられないようです。C++としてコンパイルしていますから、soファイルのエクスポート名がズレたようです。

以下のような jni_part.h を作って、jni_part.c の先頭で `#include "jni_part.h"` すると直りますか？

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_foo_MainActivity_foo(JNIEnv*,
  jobject, jlong, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

追記：本質的には、Java/nativeメソッド宣言に対応するC++/関数宣言にて`extern "C"`指定が必要となります。

C++では関数オーバーロード等を実現するため、名前マングリング(name mangling)とよばれる変形処理が行われており、ビルドされたSOファイルにはこの変形された名前が出力されます。一方、JNIでは「関数の名前」に頼ってネイティブ関数を探そうとしますので、質問文中にあるような`UnsatisfiedLinkError`例外になります。

`extern "C"`指定により名前マングリングを抑止し、ソースコード上の関数名そのままをSOファイルに出力させます。なお、手抜きをするなら jni_part.h を作らずに、ネイティブ関数定義を全部囲う`extern "C" {`～`}`を書けばOKです。

```c
extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_foo_MainActivity_foo(JNIEnv*,
  jobject, jlong matCameraAddr, jlong matViewAddr)
{
  // 何か処理
}

// さらに他ネイティブメソッドの実装...
}
```

Comment: その通りに実施してみたところ、出来ました。ありがとうございます。